# How to convert simple iterator to javascript generator

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, iterator, generator

**[CODEPEN](https://codepen.io/matthewharwood/pen/JvMQYo?editors=0011)**

*Trying to wrap my head around generator and I just don't get it.*

I have a simple non generator iterator class called `KeyGen` that I would like to rewrite using JS [generators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Generator):

*If this isn't what generators are suppose to do than please leave a comment and I'll close*

```
class KeyGen {
  constructor(numOfKeys) {
    this.keys = new Array(numOfKeys).fill(0).map((i, index) => index);
    this.iteratorCount = 0;
  }

  keyIterator() {
    return {
      next: () => this.keys[this.iteratorCount++]
    }
  }
}

const keyGen = new KeyGen(4);

console.log(keyGen.keyIterator().next());
console.log(keyGen.keyIterator().next());
console.log(keyGen.keyIterator().next());
console.log(keyGen.keyIterator().next());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A generator would be a good fit here, but you should note that your original code is not the same as generator. For a generator, the `next` call should return an object with two keys, `value` and `done`.

To convert to a generator function, you just need to build the initial list to iterate over in the same way you do now, but then you can just use a normal for loop to `yield` each element one by one.

Example:

```js
function* KeyGen(numOfKeys) {
    const keys = Array(numOfKeys)
      .fill(0)
      .map((i, index) => index);
      
    for (let key of keys) {
      yield key;
    }
}

const keyGen = KeyGen(4);

console.log(keyGen.next())
console.log(keyGen.next())
console.log(keyGen.next())
console.log(keyGen.next())
console.log(keyGen.next())

// For extra coolness, note that for/of loops are designed to work with generators:
for (let key of KeyGen(4)) {
    console.log(key)
}
```

Comment: if it was a method of a class the * goes behind the *methodName yeah?

Comment: Yes. The `*` will go before the method name. EG: `class Foo { *bar() { yield 1 } }`

Answer (score 2):

It's pretty straightforward, just declare the array and then `yield` each element:

```js
function* gen(length) {
  const keys = Array.from({ length }, (_, i) => i);
  for (const key of keys) yield key;
}

const iter = gen(3);
console.log(iter.next().value);
console.log(iter.next().value);
console.log(iter.next().value);
```